# Awk command to print all the lines except the last three lines

Tags: command-line, awk

I want to print all the lines except the last three lines from the input through awk only. Please note that my file contains n number of lines.

**For example,**

`file.txt` contains,

```
foo
bar
foobar
barfoo
last
line
```

I want the output to be,

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

I know it could be possible through the combination of `tac` and `sed` or `tac` and `awk`

```
$ tac file | sed '1,3d' | tac
foo
bar
foobar

$ tac file | awk 'NR==1{next}NR==2{next}NR==3{next}1' | tac
foo
bar
foobar
```

But i want the output through awk only.

Comment: one easy way: `head -n -3 file.txt`

Comment: @souravc yep, i know :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's ever-so clunky but you can add every line to an array and at the end —when you know the length— output everything but the last 3 lines.

```
... | awk '{l[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-3; i++) print l[i]}'
```

Another (more efficient *here*) approach is manually stacking in three variables:

```
... | awk '{if (a) print a; a=b; b=c; c=$0}'
```

`a` only prints after a line has moved from `c` to `b` and then into `a` so this limits it to three lines. The immediate upsides are it doesn't store all the content in memory and it shouldn't cause buffering issues (`fflush()` after printing if it does) but the downside here is it's not simple to scale this up. If you want to skip the last 100 lines, you need 100 variables and 100 variable juggles.

If awk had `push` and `pop` operators for arrays, it would be easier.

Or we could pre-calculate the number of lines and how far we actually want to go with `$(($(wc -l < file) - 3))`. This is relatively useless for *streamed* content but on a file, works pretty well:

```
awk -v n=$(($(wc -l < file) - 3)) 'NR<n' file
```

Typically speaking you'd just use `head` though:

```
$ seq 6 | head -n-3
1
2
3
```

---

Using [terdon's benchmark](https://askubuntu.com/a/475804/449) we can actually see how these compare. I thought I'd offer a full comparison though:

- `head`: 0.018s (me)
- `awk` + `wc`: 0.169s (me)
- `awk` 3 variables: 0.178s (me)
- `awk` double-file: 0.322s (terdon)
- `awk` circular buffer: 0.355s (Scrutinizer)
- `awk` for-loop: 0.693s (me)

The fastest solution is using a C-optimised utility like `head` or `wc` handle the heavy lifting things but in *pure* `awk`, the manually rotating stack is king for now.

Comment: it would be better if you replace `l` with `a` for better understanding.

Comment: It's just a variable name, in this case short (in my mind) for "lines".

Comment: i memorized it as `a` which means array.

Comment: +1, `head` is the best choice.

Comment: @glennjackman, but the OP asked for `awk` only. Besides, `head` used with `-n-3` is a GNU extension and is not specified by POSIX .

Comment: Yes, it's a GNU extension. However, this is Ask *Ubuntu*, so I don't think that's a problem ...

Comment: @glennjackman Ow, yes, that's right :)

Comment: +1 for matching your username with your behaviour ;)

Answer (score 6):

For minimal memory usage, you could use a circular buffer:

```
awk 'NR>n{print A[NR%n]} {A[NR%n]=$0}' n=3 file
```

By using the mod operator on line numbers we have at most n array entries.

Taking the example of n=3:

On line 1 `NR%n` equals 1, line 2 produces 2 and line 3 produces 0 and line 4 evaluates to 1 again..

```
Line 1 -> A[1]
Line 2 -> A[2]
Line 3 -> A[0]
Line 4 -> A[1]
Line 5 -> A[2]
...
```

When we get to line 4, `A[NR%n]` contains the content of line 1. So that gets printed and `A[NR%n]` gets the content of line 4. The next line (line 5) the original content of line 2 gets printed and so on, until we get to the end. What remains unprinted is the content of the buffer, which contains the last 3 lines...

Comment: works. It would be better if you explain your command little bit.

Comment: Hi, @AvinashRaj: Added an explanation..

Comment: Why'd you delete this? I like it.

Comment: Hi @Oli , I had the impression that the OP was happy with the GNU `head` solution, which in Ubuntu is available, so I thought my post was not so relevant..

Answer (score 2):

You can also process the file twice to avoid keeping *anything* in memory:

```
awk '{if(NR==FNR){c++}else if(FNR<=c-3){print}}' file file
```

The trick here is the `NR==FNR` test. `NR` is the current line number and `FNR` is the current line number of the current file. If more than one file is passed as input, `FNR` will be equal to `NR` only while the first file is being processed. This way, we quickly get the number of lines in the first file and save it as `c`. Since the "two" files are actually the same one, we now know the number of lines we want so we only print if this is one of them.

While you might think this will be slower than the other approaches, it is actually faster since there is next to no processing going on. Everything is done using internal `awk` tools (`NR` and `FNR`) apart from a single arithmetic comparison. I tested on a 50MB file with one million lines created with this command:

```
for i in {500000..1000000}; do 
    echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog $i" >> file; 
done
```

As you can see, the times are almost identical but the approach I provided here is marginally faster Oli's first suggestion (but slower than the others):

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do ( 
    time awk '{if(NR==FNR){c++}else if(FNR<=c-3){print}}' file file > /dev/null ) 2>&1 | 
       grep -oP 'real.*?m\K[\d\.]+'; 
  done | awk '{k+=$1}END{print k/10" seconds"}'; 
0.4757 seconds

$  for i in {1..10}; do ( 
    time awk '{l[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-3; i++) print l[i]}' file > /dev/null ) 2>&1 | 
        grep -oP 'real.*?m\K[\d\.]+'; 
   done | awk '{k+=$1}END{print k/10" seconds"}'; 
0.5347 seconds
```

Comment: I was thinking similarly - you could do a slightly golfed version `awk 'NR!=FNR {FNR==1?c=NR:1} FNR<c-3' file file` using the `NR,FNR` builtins instead of a separate count (`c` here is the file length _plus one_) and default print action.

Comment: Don't leave your benchmarking *there*. The circular buffer is as fast as yours and my second approach (three variables) is actually twice as fast as yours.

Comment: @Oli so it is indeed. Sorry, since I was expecting mine to be slower, I only took the first solution from the accepted answer and was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: The cleverness of FNR and NR usage

Comment: even simpler version: `awk 'FNR<=NR-FNR-3' file file`; explanation: `NR-FNR` is the number of lines in files completely processed so far (0 for the first file, and number of lines in the first file for the second one)

Comment: @mik please post separate answers with different approaches or just edit them into one of the existing ones instead of leaving comments. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss, and can be deleted without warning. That said, this is a really nice approach so it should have its own answer!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was specifically about `awk`, but for brevity one could always use:

```
head -n -3
```